# Log-out after opening firebug

Tags: firebug, cakephp-2.0

i have an web application in Cakephp.

Application session gets destroyed and user gets logged out after enabling firebug.

I have never faced this problem while using other frameworks like zend. I am using Cakephp for the first time and facing this problem.

How can i fix this problem.

Comment: Check possible session/cookie alteration, logout call/request while initiating firebug. Try same in chrome developer tool to cross verify cause.  if you have app access, debug server side requests & web server log to get insight of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that For each request HTTP_USER_AGENT is checked in the session and when we enable/disable firebug, userAgent value gets changed.

Thus we get logged out if we enable/disable firebug.

To resolve this we can set **Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', true);** in /app/config/core.php.

Comment: I think we need to set `Session.checkAgent` to **`false`** in order to get rid of logging in each time after enable/disable Firebug.